# IdentityServer4 - Call an API as a User from MVC

Tags: identityserver4

I'm getting my knickers in a twist trying to understand how to call an API protected via IdentityServer4.

Basically, I have the following sites: 
- an IdentityServer application, 
- a web API and 
- a client web application.

My setup is just like the IdentityServer samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity).

I define a `Client` which represents my client web application, and an `APIResource` which represents my Web Api.

From within my client web application I want to make an HTTP call to the WebAPI, but I want to appear as if I am the logged in user, so I want to make the 'email' scope available to the Web Api.

The way I'm doing from within the Web Application is to grab the 'access_token', and to pass it to the Web API:

```
var accessToken = await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync($"access_token");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
```

This allows me to call the Client, so the authorization step is working, but the User Claims on the Web Api do not have the appropriate scopes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `access_token` can contain claim information in IdentityServer4. The required claims must be specified in the ApiResource definition.

Otherwise, you have to send a JWT id_token along with the request.

```
  new ApiResource(ApiResourceNames.SomeApiAccess, "Access to some api.", new List<string>(){
                    new IdentityResources.OpenId().Name,
                    new IdentityResources.Profile().Name,
                    new IdentityResources.Email().Name
                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add scopes in your web api like

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
    ApiName = "api1",

    AllowedScopes = { "api1.read", "api1.write" }
});
```

How did you configure your web api? Post the code if it still doesn't work!